# I need a concept for an application like an alarm clock

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to make an application like an alarm clock, which runs in background without any UI interaction.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: instead of calling your code on button click, call it on activity create. That's obvious, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `service` for this purpose.

> **A service is a component that runs in the background to perform long-running operations without needing to interact with the user and
>   it works even if application is destroyed.**
>
> **A Service does not provide a user
>   interface. Another application component can start a service, and it
>   continues to run in the background even if the user switches to
>   another application.**

Try this tutorials:

[android services tutorial 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)

[android services tutorial 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)